# HABTM messing me up - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a simple HABM relationship set up between users and children.

If a child belongs to you, I want you to see the child AND the name of other users that this child object belongs to. For some reason I cannot print the name of the other users the child belongs to.

I select as such:

```
@children = Child.all(:include => :users, :conditions => ["users.id = ? AND enrolled = ?", current_user.id, true])
```

and try to print as such:

```
<% for user in child.users%>
  <% if can? :manage, Child %>
    <a rel='tipsy'><%= link_to '[#{user.first_and_last_name}]', edit_child_path(child), :title => "#{user.updateChoice}"%></a>
  <%else%>  
    <a rel='tipsy'><%= link_to '[#{user.first_and_last_name}]', new_parentnote_path, :title => "#{user.updateChoice}"%></a>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

It selects the right children but DOES NOT print the other users' name. Only the current user's name.

If I select all children

```
Child.all
```

everything works as expected. All  names get printed which tells me it is not my authentication system doing something fishy but something else...probably the way I select the children although I tried several ways =(

I am not sure if I am missing something really obvious but this has puzzled me for hours.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT - Add Schema**

As requested bellow here is the schema. The relationship is set up fine as far as I can tell. It is just getting multiple users based on current_user that is not happening as explained above. *If I use the query above even though the child has multiple users (I see that by doing a child.count) it will only print the current user's name for some reason it is not fetching the other users name that the child belongs to as well.*

```
  create_table "children_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "child_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

Then I have children.

```
  create_table "children", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "enrolled",            :default => true
    t.datetime "unenrolled_datetime"
  end
```

and users

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    ........   other stuff to reset password etc
  end
```

Comment: The quotes in your `link_to` look wrong...

Comment: Thanks for caching that. It the was a issue when I took out the DIVs to past it here as the div was not relavant to the question. Put the divs back in there exactly as I have them for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the children of a user, and at the same time, get all the other parents?

An easy way to list the children of a user and display the parents of each children would be:

```
@children = current_user.children

<%= @children.each do |child| %>
    <h2><%= child.first_name %></h2>
    <%= @child.parents.each do |parent| %>
       <p><%= parent.first_name %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

ps:

in Children model

```
has_many :children_users
has_many :parents, :through => :children_users, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
```

Comment: Robin, you saved the day. Thank you. I did not user has_many :through but your example worked with my current HABTM. I replace `@children = Child.all(:include => :users, :conditions => ["users.id = ? AND enrolled = ?", current_user.id, true])` with @children = current_user.children` and it just worked. I should have thought of/tried that. Kudos!

Comment: My pleasure ;) Also, it's a detail, but the `if can? :manage, Child` part could be outside the loop: `can_manage_children = can? :manage, Child;` and then in the loop, just do `<a rel='tipsy'><%= link_to '[#{user.first_and_last_name}]', can_manage_children ? edit_child_path(child) : new_parentnote_path, :title => "#{user.updateChoice}"%></a>`. Also, you're using rails 3.1, so you should update the way you're writing queries :).

Comment: I am updating the way I write queries to .where instead of .find and .all. I am still getting the hang of HABTM queries in general. This is my first stab at it.  =)

Answer (score 0):

I belive it's the condition `"users.id = ? ", current_user.id` that makes loading only the children of the current_user, and subsequently when you iterate over those the only user there, is current user.

What you probbly want is select based on `children.user_id`:

```
@children = Child.where(user_id: current_user.id, enrolled: true).includes(:users)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Clyfe. However, I do not have a child.user_id column. I tried your suggestion and got (PGError: ERROR:  column children.user_id does not exist).

Currently in Dev. There are only 2 children in the db. Both have multiple users. I am very confused why it is not working.

Comment: Please provide all the details on your schema and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: added the schema and details on what I a trying to accomplish. Thank for your help Clyfe.